# MultiValueDictKeyError at /profiles/adminKaLogin/ Django

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-views

So I am trying to create a site which takes in input of vendor choices and time period from the user, and accordingly fetches data from the models. The first two radio buttons are to select the vendor, and the remaining are for specifying the time frame. I am getting the above mentioned error for 'inlineDefaultRadiosExample1' while doing the same. Given below are the relevant files:

views.py:

```
if 'form1' in request.POST:
            vendor_choice = request.POST["inlineDefaultRadiosExample1"]
            date_choice = request.POST["inlineDefaultRadiosExample1"]
            x = employee.objects.get(name = request.user)
            y = vendor.objects.get(id = vendor_choice)
            if date_choice == 1:
                d = transaction.objects.filter(ven_id=y, emp_id = x, timestamp__gte = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30))
            elif date_choice == 1:
                d = transaction.objects.filter(ven_id=y, emp_id = x, timestamp__gte = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=60))
            else:
                d = transaction.objects.filter(vendor_id=y, emp_id = x, timestamp__gte = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=180))    

            return render(request, 'profiles/adminKaLogin.html', {'model':d})
```

Models.py

```
class vendor(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class employee(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class transaction(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    debit = models.IntegerField()
    credit = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
```

The HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profiles/adminKaLogin/">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline1" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample" value="1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">Vendor 1</label>
            </div>

            <!-- Default inline 2-->
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline2" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample" value="2">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline2">Vendor 2</label>
            </div>
        <br>  
        <h3> Select time period</h3>

            <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInlines1" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample1" value="1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInlines1">1 Month</label>
            </div>  
            <!-- Default inline 2-->
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInlines2" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample1" value="2">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInlines2">2 Months</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInlines3" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample1" value="6">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInlines3">6 Months</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="form1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You defined an `<input>` with the same name three times?

Comment: So that I can choose only one among them..?

Comment: I need to choose one among the two vendors, and one time frame among the three specified.